# how to make <Span> above a button, clickable (as the button)?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index, positioning

[See this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vew8bv6y/)

I want the "eye" icon on the one hand to appear as it is now (above the button, so I don't think a z-index would help), yet on the other hand I want to have the button clickable at all its surface, meaning in the eye area as well.

Also, is there a better way to position the eye? as once I'm using different text then "Click me", I would have to accordingly set the absolute position of the eye. any way to define it better?

```
<form action="1.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Click Me"><span class="fa fa-eye fa-lg foo" "></span>
</form>

.foo{
     color:red;
    font-size:1.7em;
    position: absolute;
    height: 11px;
    top: 18px;
    left: 15px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    line-height: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: .5em .9em .5em 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use `<input type="submit">` or could you use a `button`?

Comment: must use input, ok i'll add code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In terms of making it clickable, you could add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the element. This essentially allows you to click through the element.

[**Updated Example**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7mof9pwd/)

```
.foo {
    pointer-events: none;
    color: red;
    /* Other styles.. */
}
```

Support for this property can be [**found here**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

---

Another option would be to wrap both of the elements in a `label`. When the label is clicked, the `input` element is triggered, thereby resolving the issue.

[**Example Here**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kaogd2mc/)

```
<label>
    <span class="fa fa-eye fa-lg foo"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Click Me"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks, I guess it's not supported though on IE9 and 8? is there a solution for these IE versions as well?

Comment: just saw your support link, is there another option that's supported on IE10 (maybe even 9 and 8)?

Comment: awesome, two questions:
1. I want the button to change color on hover, is there a way to do this with the label you suggest, while hovering over the `span`? (as I see it's impossible with the current code)
2. Is there a way to combine both of your solutions, like having the `pointer-events` as default, and the label as a fallback for IE7-10?

Comment: @rockyraw Like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xzL1819n/), or [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/r4d01ctd/). Not sure which one you're after - probably the former.

Comment: not exactly, what I mean is that basically, I have a pretty long css code for button:hover (gradient). so when someone is hovering over the button, the appearance change. I want to have the exact change in appearance in the whole button surface, meaning when someone hovers over the span as well.

Comment: [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xzL1819n/1/) for the problem; update: ok, looks like your suggestion works, though is there a way to avoid using the same css code both in the `button:hover` and in your new label def.?

Comment: @rockyraw You would use the selector `label:hover .button` - [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jfjcon0x/). You will probably want to restructure the HTML/CSS like [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/x7zzofu1/), though.

Comment: might be a little greedy, but is there a way to make this span-hover workaround to work in IE8-9 as well? :)

Comment: @rockyraw It *does* work in IE8/9. Linear-gradients just isn't supported in those browsers - http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients